# C++ QML Plugin with python

Tags: c++, qt, qml, pyside2

I am trying to embed a c++ qml plugin in a python project. I use `Qt5.15.2` with `mingw6.1.0` and `pyside2 5.15.2`. It works in Linux and macOS - already tested. But on windows, it says "plugin cannot be loaded for module "a.plugin.video": Cannot load library `D:a/plugin/video/plugin.dll`.The specified module could not be found". I have a qmldir, which points to a plugin. QML engine sees it but it refuses to load it. Why is that? Do I need to create some sort of binding for *.dll. If so, why is it called a "QML" plugin which is supposed to be loaded by the QML engine no matter where you put it?
QML plugin builds successfully because it works with c++ executable. I use Cmake for plugin building. The problem lies between the python and dll/qml plugin on Windows. The same situation works perfectly in Linux/MacOs. Python QML engine loads .so/.dylib successfully. What am I missing?

main.py

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


if __name__ == "__main__":
app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.addImportPath("./")
    qml_file = Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "main.qml"
    engine.load(str(qml_file))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import a.plugin.video 1.0

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    MyItem {

    }
}
```

```
qmldir
-
module a.plugin.video
plugin plugin

Project tree
-
D:\untitled: main.py main.qml
D:\untitled\a\plugin\video: qmldir plugin.dll
```

Comment: `D:a/plugin/video/plugin.dll` is probably a wrong path

Comment: Double checked. If it was the path problem the different type of error would appear - like plugin is not installed. I checked pyside library files in both linux and windows and saw that linux .so files could be loaded by python interpreter in run time whereas in windows for each .dll there are .pyd file. Maybe it is the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i was using mingw compiler no matter which version. PySide2 works through shiboken bindings with Qt libraries (.dlls) which by itself is built using mvsc compiler.
On Linux and MacOS it is working due to compiler consistency (my plugin built with gcc and pyside2 libraries built with gcc and the same on Mac).